# I want run 3 methods at the same time and the others wait until any methods is finish

Tags: c#

Hi I want run 3 methods at the same time and the others wait until any methods is  finish. How can i do this?  Here's what I've done so far.

```
public static List<Action> actions;
 public static int ms = 1;    
 public static void s1()
        {
             actions = new List<Action>();
        actions.Add(drivers1);
        actions.Add(drivers2);
        actions.Add(drivers3);
        actions.Add(drivers4);
        var maxThreads = 3;

        int j = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            if (j == 1){
                if (ms <= 3) {
                while (true) { 

                        if (actions.Count() < 1)
                        {
                            j = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(actions[0]));
                            thread.Start();



                        }
               }
                }
                else
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (ms <= 3)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

here image example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_qK2Yu2RjebAfKFdYFovShGR5GiuwzBI

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider Wrapping your methods in a Task
then you can easily use [Task.WaitAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany?view=netframework-4.8) Method

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => Method1() );
var task2 = Task.Run(() => Method2() );
var task3 = Task.Run(() => Method3() );
Task.WaitAny(task1, task2, task3);
```

note that tasks wrap exceptions so in case u done this and any exception happened in Methods 1,2,3 the catch block will never be executed   :

```
 try
            {
                Task task1 = Task.Run(() => Method1());
                Task task2 = Task.Run(() => Method2());
                Task task3 = Task.Run(() => Method3());
                Task.WaitAny(task1, task2, task3);

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {    
                throw;
            }
```

but you case still get the status of the Task variable itself

Comment: Your solution is the very right. But If you can leave some example code here and that would be great